# NOAA CO-OPS API request forbidden

Tags: python, api, python-requests, noaa

I am using python's requests library to retrieve tidal information from noaa's co-ops api and keep getting an error 403 forbidden response.  I am using python 2.7 on pythonanywhere if that makes a difference.  This is my code:

```
headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Safari/537.36',
'From':'iancissel@gmail.com'
}
boston_id='8443970'
url='http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?date=today&station=8443970&product=high_low&datum=STND&units=english&time_zone=lst&format=json'
r=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print r
```

Comment: Works fine from my command line on Ubuntu 14.4, python 2.7

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was pythonanywhere issue

Comment: figured it out.....noaa tides and currents api is not on pythonanywhere's whitelist